# Turn the pants over

Tags: vocabulary

A pair of pants is inside out. How to tell another to make it correct?

1. Turn them over
2. Take outside in

Answer (score 3):

I would say

> Turn them the right way out

or perhaps better:

> Turn them the right side out

"Turn them over" would just flip front to back.

"Take outside in" needs qualifying, because currently the correct "outside" is inside and that's what we don't want. Hence my use of the work *right*

[Example of usage of "right way out"](http://sewoverit.co.uk/betty-dress-sewalong-no-6-attaching-the-facing-and-assembling-the-shoulders/)

Comment: Thank you. How about "turn them out"?

Comment: "turn them out" would be understood, but has a meaning in a different context: eject some people from a home, my suggestions are the sort of standard phrasing.

Comment: In my neck of the woods there'd be no article: *Turn them right side out*.

Comment: Agreed, StoneyB, that is a common alternative; I believe both are used - these are big woods ...

Comment: "outside in" certainly does have usage, though, particularly when coupled with "inside out".

Comment: Certainly does, but in my neck of the woods it mean the same as "inside out", right!?!

Comment: _Take something in_ is also a [phrasal verb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/take-sth-in) used in tailoring and alterations. I'd be careful about handing a seamstress a pair of my pants, and asking her to to "take outside in".

Comment: If I were to ask our housekeeper to turn a pair of trousers _outside in_, she would reply: "Huh?"

Comment: @djna You vastly overestimate the size of the woods. Not one native speaker in a million would understand what you mean by _turn them out._ A large percentage would ask "Turn them out of what?" and some would say "Where are you from?"

Comment: Not even when pointing at a pair of trousers that are inside out? But then I am on occasion asked where I'm from, or indeed to go back there.